# Testing with moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, moq

I'm trying to work out this whole testing thing, and have decided to start with an existing application that we use to record phone calls to the office.  The app is a c#, mvvm, desktop application and for now at least, I'm just trying to work out how the testing framework operates.  I have created a new test project, added reference to moq and am trying to run a test that verifies a method is called by another method.

The method I'm testing is simply a Command to close a window.  The command uses messaging to communicate with a View Service to actually do the closing.  Relevant code:

**BaseViewModel**:

```
public RelayCommand CloseWindowCommand { get; set; }

public BaseViewModel(IDataAccessService dataAccess)
{
  ...
  CloseWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(CloseWindow);
}

internal virtual void CloseWindow()
{
  SendCloseRequest();
}

void SendCloseRequest()
{
  System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("called BaseVM.SendCloseRequest");
  Messenger.Default.Send<RequestCloseMessage>(new RequestCloseMessage(this), this);
}
```

**ViewService**:

```
private Window CreateWindow(ViewModelBase vm)
{
  ...
  window.DataContext = vm;
  window.Closed += OnClosed;

  // listen for the close event
  Messenger.Default.Register<RequestCloseMessage>(window, vm, OnRequestClose);
  return window;
}

public void OnRequestClose(RequestCloseMessage message)
{
  System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("called ViewService.OnRequestClose");

  var window = OpenedWindows.SingleOrDefault(w => w.DataContext == message.ViewModel);
  if (window != null)
  {
    Messenger.Default.Unregister<RequestCloseMessage>(window, message.ViewModel, OnRequestClose);
    if (message.DialogResult != null)
    {
      // trying to set the dialog result of the non-modal window will result in InvalidOperationException
      window.DialogResult = message.DialogResult;
    }
    window.Close();
  }
}
```

**BaseViewModelTest**  (1):

```
[TestMethod]
public void SendCloseMesage_Calls_OnRequestClose()
{
  Mock<IDataAccessService> mockProxy = new Mock<IDataAccessService>();
  Mock<IViewService> mockView = new Mock<IViewService>();
  var vm = new BaseViewModel(mockProxy.Object);
  Mock<RequestCloseMessage> mockCloseMessage = new Mock<RequestCloseMessage>((ViewModelBase)vm, null);

  vm.CloseWindowCommand.Execute(null);
  mockView.Verify(v => v.OnRequestClose(mockCloseMessage.Object));
}
```

When I run the test it fails with:

```
Moq.MockException: 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: v => v.OnRequestClose
```

So, I tried to just test that the command calls the method in the VM:

***BaseViewModelTest*** (2):

```
[TestMethod]
public void SendCloseMesage_Calls_CloseWindow()
{
  Mock<IDataAccessService> mockProxy = new Mock<IDataAccessService>();
  Mock<IViewService> mockView = new Mock<IViewService>();
  //var vm = new BaseViewModel(mockProxy.Object);
  Mock<BaseViewModel> mockVM = new Mock<BaseViewModel>(mockProxy);
  Mock<RequestCloseMessage> mockCloseMessage = new Mock<RequestCloseMessage>((ViewModelBase)mockVM.Object, null);

  mockVM.Object.CloseWindowCommand.Execute(null);
  mockVM.Verify(vm => vm.CloseWindow());
}
```

This comes back with a similar error:

```
Moq.MockException: 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: vm => vm.CloseWindow()
```

However, in both cases, the `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("called <MethodName>");` statement is called as I have to deal with the dialog box.  (I added the MessageBox commands for confirmation.  The error is the same with or without them.)

Why is `Moq` telling me the method isn't called, when the `MessageBox.Show()` command in the method is being called?

PS:  I'm not overly worried about whether testing the window closes is worth it, at the moment, I'm just trying to make sure I can test one method is calling another.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [method `MessageBox.Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox.show) is a `static` method. If you call it directly, Moq has no chance of knowing that.

In addition, do you even pass (or inject) your `mockCloseMessage` to your subject-under-test?

Comment: I just added the `MessageBox.Show()` calls *inside the method I was verifying* to ensure that the methods were actually being called.  I didn't realise the message needed to be passed; I thought the verification was just on the method being called, not the arguments given to it.  The `SendCloseRequest()` method actually creates its `RequestCloseMessage`.  I just created one in the test to satisfy other mock construction requirements.  Can you suggest how I'd test the Command - given the Message doesn't get created till further down the method chain?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mockView.Verify(v => v.OnRequestClose(mockCloseMessage.Object));
> ```

This will verify that `OnRequestClose` was called at least once with the instance `mockCloseMessage.Object`, which seems not true in your case.

You should use `It.IsAny<>()` (or another mathing argument function, check the [docs](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)):

```
mockView.Verify(v => v.OnRequestClose(It.IsAny<RequestCloseMessage>()));
```

---

**Update**

After looking again at your code, there are some other points to mention:

The idea of mocking is when you would like to test a specific class that is dependent on other classes. Then, you would mock those dependencies classes in order to isolate and simplify your test.

It seems that you have created some mocks, but they are not injected to the object you are testing.

Another issue is that you have a dependency upon the `Messenger` class and a registration procedure has to be done, in order for the service to receive the event. You are mixing too much here, and make assumptions. To me, it seems that you are missing the whole point of unit test. Your test relies on actions that happens elsewhere.

Your code as is, doesn't seem easy to test.

Comment: Going to check docs, but your suggested change still came back with `Moq.MockException: 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: v => v.OnRequestClose(It.IsAny<RequestCloseMessage>())`

Comment: Yes, There's another issue. You verify the call on the mock of `mockView`, but again it is not injected anywhere...

Comment: Thanks for the frank advice.  Yes, I am just trying to wrap my head around testing within mvvm and am simply trying to check that when the Close Window command is invoked, that it calls the related method in the VM (originally that it called the method on the view service).  I chose that command as it has no params and simply closes the window, so I thought it would be an easy start.  Adding the `Messenger` dependency only happened because the test runner was complaining that it couldn't find the correct constructor.  What would be a better way to do this do you think?